# How to take a TextBox control as an argument for a Sub in class libraries?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I'm new and still learning in VB.net. I'm trying to create a Solution with two project: a Windows Application Forms project and a Class Library project. Everything goes fine until I try to add a System.Windows.Forms class to my Library Project.

My code is like this:

In Windows Application Forms project: MainForm class

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub btnMessage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMessage.Click
        Dim msg As New Message(txtMessage, "Testing")
        msg.showMessage()
    End Sub

End Class
```

In Class Library project: Message Class

```
Namespace MyLibraries

    Public Class Message

        Public Property box As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Public Property msg As String

        Sub New(ByRef txtBox As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Optional ByVal txtMsg As String = "")
            msg = txtMsg
        End Sub

        Public Sub showMessage()
            txtBox.Text = txtMsg
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

That code give me an error:

> Could not load type 'MyLibraries.Message' from assembly 'MyLibraries, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

If I put the Message Class in main project or I take away box property in that class, the program work fine. But, what I'm trying to achieve is to create a Class that can take Forms or Controls as it's argument and save that class in a library so I can use later in other project.

I've searched and most of the suggestions that I found are talking about Assembly whatever that I can't understand and I can't make it works even though I'm following that suggestion step by step.

Maybe some experienced programmers here can make it simple to me for understanding this problem? I appreciate if someone can give me a basic concept of that Assembly signing or something.

(Sorry for my bad English. English is not my native language.)

**UPDATE**

I have done what JRLambert said. I create a new solution with two project and copied all of my code before there. And then I add reference to each project like what Olivier Jacot-Descombes said. And thanks, my program works. But, i still don't understand what's wrong and why it's happen? Can anyone give a simple explanation?

Comment: Is there an InnerException?

Comment: No. it said TypeLoadException

Comment: What will you do with the TextBox in the class library?  Why not just pass the Text property?

Answer (score 1):

When you build your project, your class library is in a different folder then your forms app. Either change the build property of your class library project so it builds to the same folder, or copy that dll to the folder where your forms app is running.

Comment: This alone won't help. You need a reference to this dll or, better, a project reference, if both projects are in the same solution. Then Visual Studio will take care of copying the dll to the right place automatically.

Comment: There is already a reference to the project, else it would not compile since he is referencing a class in the class library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a project reference to your library project in your application project.

See: [Managing Project References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx). See especially the section on the handling of *project-to-project references*.

The projects in a solution are isolated. I.e., they don't know anything about the other projects in this or other solutions. In order to make the code editor, the forms designer and the compiler know about a type defined in another solution, you must add a reference to this other project if it is in the same solution, or to the dll if the project is in another solution (or if you have a single dll without solution or project).